# One-liner to initialize list from another list

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, initialization, java-stream

I would like to initialize List of my Dto the shortest way possible. Right now I'm using:

```
public List<SomeItemDto> itemsToDto(List<SomeItem> items) {
    List<SomeItemDto> itemsDto = new ArrayList<SomeItemDto>();
    for (SomeItem item : items) {
        itemsDto.add(itemToDto(item));
    }
    return itemsDto;
}
```

Is there any way of making it a one-liner?

Comment: Use the stream API.

Comment: Is there a reason not to simply use [List.addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)) ?

Comment: @S.L.Barth conversion of the objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using `stream` and further `map`ping as:

```
return items.stream()
            .map(item -> itemToDto(item)) // map SomeItem to SomeItemDto
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `map(this::itemToDto)` will be even shorter

Comment: @ernest_k agreed, just keeping it as a lambda still, since in a way mapping can be conveyed easily(IMHO) using it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `map` which basically applies a function to an element

```
List<SomeItemDto> itemsDto = items.stream().map(item -> itemToDto(item))
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using a third-party library, you can use the [`ListIterate`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/utility/ListIterate.html) utility from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections) with any `List`.

```
List<SomeItemDto> itemsDto = ListIterate.collect(items, this::itemToDto);
```

If items was a [`MutableList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html) from Eclipse Collections, you could use the API directly on the list as follows:

```
List<SomeItemDto> itemsDto = items.collect(this::itemToDto);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.